# Data Cursor not moving upon pressing the arrow keys in scatter plot

Tags: matlab

I find the Data Cursor in Matlab a very powerful tool when plotting data and debugging code. However, it often does not behave as expected. For instance, consider the following minimal example:

```
x = randn(1,10);
y = randn(1,10);
scatter(x,y)
```

If I click on a data point with the Data Cursor, and then press any of the arrow keys on my keyboard, the data cursor does not move between the different data points plotted, as would be expected, and as indeed happens in other of my scatter plots (with code too complex to paste here).

If I change the scatter to a plot, with data points not connected by a line,

```
plot(x,y, 'o')
```

then the Data Cursor moves again when pressing the arrows. However, the scatter function has features that the plot function does not have. I didn't find it written anywhere in matlab's documentation that data cursor does not work with 'scatter'.

Any ideas when/why this happens, would be really appreciated. I am using Matlab 2016a on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Typically one creates a `scatter` plot because the data points are not ordered; and thus, one doesn't want to suggest an order by drawing lines between points.
That being said, it is odd that the scatter plot should have once allowed to move between points, since there is no order in which it could (the only order it could move is along the data as provided but that would cause the data pointer to go wild in the axis... letting it move along the x- or y-coordinate would force matlab to do a sorting in the background, which potentially eats up computing power + memory). Of course, it is something different if one uses `plot` and forces it to show only the markers. Still it is a plot of ordered data.

I have R2018b installed and also don't see any reaction if pressing the arrow keys.

Comment: Thanks. I'd still find the arrow keys shortcut useful even for scatter plots, as a way to quickly check the coordinates of points who follow one another in the list of coordinates (x-y pairs)

Comment: That is right but can maintain this feature by mimicking a `scatter` plot with  `plot(...,'o')` as you suggested yourself

Comment: Except that  I thought the scatter function has features that the plot function does not have, even though no examples come to mind right now :)